# Problem with more than 10 HDDs

Tags: pi-4, hard-drive

Problem - with more than 10 HDDs on a Pi using Raspbian.

I can only mount 9 HDDs on the Usb 3 port via 16 port USB-Hub - 10th Hdd not moutable

- having the 10th HDD on the USB2 port.

But the 11th HDD wont even appear (e.g. sda1 to sdj1 appear but no sdk1)

does someone have a hint for me how to solve this?

- all usb HDDs are externaly powered
- in addition i´m having a 100 watt powered 16 Port USB hub

so it souldnt be a power issue...

Comment: the problem may be the USB hub